# Number theory-Gaussian primes proof

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $\pi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\pi=\alpha\beta$, for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ implies either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a unit. Then $\pi$ is a Gaussian prime.

proof.

Suppose that for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, $\pi=\alpha\beta\Rightarrow \pi|\alpha\beta$. Let $\delta=gcd(\alpha,\pi)$. So, $\delta|\alpha$ and $\delta|\pi$. We can write $\pi=\delta\gamma$, for some $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. By assumption, either $\gamma$ or $\delta$ is a unit. So we split into two cases:

- Case 1: If $\gamma$ is a unit, then $\pi=\gamma\delta \Rightarrow \pi\gamma^{-1}=\delta|\alpha \Rightarrow \pi|\alpha$.
- Case 2: If $\delta$ is a unit, then $gcd(\alpha,\pi)=1 \Rightarrow gcd(\alpha\beta,\pi\beta)=\beta$. Since $\pi|\alpha\beta$ and $\pi|\pi\beta$, then it must also divide $\beta$.

Therefore, from these to cases, we conclude that either $\pi|\alpha$, or $\pi|\beta$, which completes the definition of a Gaussian prime, as required.

I need an explanation why in the first case $\pi|\alpha$.

Comment: The hypothesis is stated incorrectly.  What you mean is this.  Suppose $\pi \in \mathbb Z[i]$ and $\pi = \alpha \beta$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb Z[i]$ implies $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a unit, but not both.  Then $\pi$ is  a prime.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected this.

Comment: Except that you have not included the "but not both". If  $\pi$ is a unit, $\pi = \alpha \beta$ implies that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are units.  But units are not primes.

Comment: Something is wrong. What is you definition of a "Gaussian prime"?

Comment: A non-unit element $\pi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is called a Gaussian prime if the following holds: if, for any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $\pi$ divides $\alpha\beta$ then $\pi$ divides $\alpha$ or $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\pi = \gamma \delta$ and $\gamma$ is a unit.
Now $\delta | \alpha$, i.e. $\alpha = \delta \nu$ for some $\nu \in \mathbb Z[i]$,
and so $\alpha = \pi \gamma^{-1} \nu$, i.e. $\pi | \alpha$.